# How many different equivalence relations S on A are there for with R ⊆ S?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose R is an equivalence relation on a set A, with four equivalence classes. How many different equivalence relations S on A are there for with R ⊆ S?

I'm not too sure how to approach this question?

Comment: Is $A$ finite ?

Comment: @HowDoIMath: It doesn’t matter whether $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Equivalence relations on the (4 element) quotient set $A/R$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the equivalence relations $S:S\supseteq R$ in question.

Answer (score 0):

Let be $\dfrac{A}{S}=\{[a],[b],[c],[d]\}$ . If $x\in[a]_S$ then $x\in[a]_R$ so $[S]\subset[R]$, all class in R is union of classes in S. You have to count the number of reunions of classes in S. The order matters because $\dfrac{A}{R}=\{[1,3],[2,4]\}=\{[2,4][3,1]\}$ Count it one to one, Answer is 15

Comment: You’ve reversed $S$ and $R$.

Answer (score 0):

four equiv relations: aRb aRc bRc bRd

1. R = {(a,a)}
2. R = {(b,b)}
3. R = {(c,c)}
4. R = {(d,d)}
5. R = {(a,a), (b,b)}
6. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c)}
7. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d)}
8. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (a,b), (b,a)}
9. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (a,c), (c,a)}
10. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (a,d), (d,a)}
11. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (b,c), (c,b)}
12. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (b,d), (d,b)}
13. R = {(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (d,d), (a,b), (b,a), (a,c), (c,a), (a,d), (d,a), (b,c), (c,b), (b,d), (d,b)}
14. R = {}

14 equivalence relations